# Custom Clone button on Quote, copies few standard fields but not all, why?

Tags: javascript, custom-button, clone, ajax-toolkit

I have a custom button, which i m using to clone Quote Object. I'm using javascript with ajax tool kit, [Like in this post.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55501/create-custom-clone-button-for-quote-object) i can clone the quote with few standard fields, but not all, for e.g, Description field doesnt copy. I also need to add some custom fields clone. what i m missing here ? please see my code snippet below.

```
// ajax toolkit<br>
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/22.0/connection.js")} 
result = sforce.connection.query("select id,opportunityid from Quote where id = '{!Quote.Id}'") 
// i added fax, phone, name these are not copied over...
window.top.location.href = 
"{!URLFOR( $Action.Quote.NewQuote ,null,[clone=1,id=Quote.Id,Fax=Quote.Fax,Phone=Quote.Phone,Name=Quote.Name, Email=Quote.Email,retURL="/"&Quote.Id],true)}&oppid=" + 
result.records.OpportunityId.
```

really appreciate any inputs.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is not the best way to do it and is difficult to maintain.

Here is a class, test method, and Button that will clone the quote and ALL related objects. You can specify if the related objects get cloned or not.

**Caveat** There is no checking on limits so as long as there are not too many related objects you are fine, but if you have too many you may get either an exception for too many SOQL or a DOM timeout (Depending on your environment). Feel free to modify it as needed as it is not a final product but a starting point:

**Class**

```
/**
 * Purpose: Clone Quote from Custom button
 * Copying all createable fields to the new clone
 * Ignores Unique fields so they must be filled in manually
 */

global class Object_Clone {

    private Static Map<ID, ID> oldIDToNewID = New Map<ID, ID>();
    private Static String errorThrown;
    @TestVisible private STATIC FINAL String TOMANYTYPES = 'Multiple Object Types were detected in the initial records';
    @TestVisible private STATIC FINAL String NORECORDS = 'No Records to clone';


    public class Object_Clone_Exception extends Exception {

    }

    /*****************************************************************************
    *   List of Objects to not clone
    ******************************************************************************/

    @TestVisible private STATIC Set<String> excludedObjects {
        get {
            if (excludedObjects == null) {
                return New Set<String>();
            } else {
                return excludedObjects;
            }
        }
    }


    /*****************************************************************************
    *   Execute Clone Method - SINGLE ID
    *       From button
    ******************************************************************************/

    webservice static String cloneObjectSingle(ID oId, boolean withChildren) {
        if (cloneObjectWithExclude(New Set<ID>{oId}, withChildren, null)) {
            //If we are here then no errors so return the URL to the new Cloned Record
            return New PageReference('/' + oldIDToNewID.get(oId)).getURL();
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }

    /*****************************************************************************
    *   Execute Clone Method - SET OF IDs
    *       NOT specifying Child Objects to Exclude if cloning children
    ******************************************************************************/

    public static Boolean cloneObjectSet(Set<ID> oId, boolean withChildren) {
        return cloneObjectWithExclude(oId, withChildren, null);
    }


    /*****************************************************************************
    *   Execute Clone Method - SET OF IDs
    *       Specifying Child Objects to Exclude if cloning children
    ******************************************************************************/

    public static boolean cloneObjectWithExclude(Set<ID> oIds, boolean withChildren, Set<String> objectsToExclude) {
        try {
            //Reset Error
            errorThrown = null;

            //Remove nulls in case they were added to a set from above methods
            oIds.remove(null);

            //Ensure that we at least have some records
            if (oIds == null || oIds.isEmpty()) {
                throw New Object_Clone_Exception(NORECORDS);
            }

            //Populate the Excluded Object Type with Force exclude as well as User Specified
            setexcludedObjects(objectsToExclude);

            //Collection of Types to clone
            Map<Schema.SObjectType, Set<ID>> types = New Map<Schema.SObjectType, Set<ID>>();

            //Build up the collection of types to Records
            for (ID oId : oIds) {
                Set<ID> existingIDsInMap = types.get(oId.getSobjectType());
                if (existingIDsInMap == null) existingIDsInMap = New Set<ID>();
                existingIDsInMap.add(oId);
                types.put(oId.getSobjectType(),existingIDsInMap);
            }

            //For each type clone the records
            for (Schema.SObjectType objtype : types.keySet()) {

                //Start the process cloning the parent with the desired options
                cloneObjects(queryForRecords(types.get(objtype), null), (withChildren == null ? false : withChildren), true);
            }

            return true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //We had an error so return nothing
            system.debug(logginglevel.error, e.getMessage() + ' - ' + e.getStackTraceString());
            errorThrown = e.getMessage();
            return false;
        }
    }

    /*****************************************************************************
    *   MAIN CLONE ENTRY METHOD
    *       Executed from one of the cloneObject Methods
    ******************************************************************************/

    private static Map<Schema.SObjectType, sObject[]> cloneObjects(sObject[] oObjs, boolean withChildren, boolean doinsert) {

        //New Records to Return
        Map<Schema.SObjectType, sObject[]> results = New Map<Schema.SObjectType, sObject[]>();

        //Collection of Related Objects and their Parent Fields
        Map<Schema.SObjectType, Schema.sObjectField[]> childRelationships;

        Map<ID, SObject> oldRecToNewRec = New Map<ID, SObject>();

        //For each record for this sObjectType
        for (sObject oldObj : oObjs) { //queryForRecords(oIds, flds)) {
            Schema.SObjectType objtype = oldObj.getSObjectType();

            //Create a new Object
            sObject newObj = oldObj.clone(false, true);

            //Populate the map with the Old ID as a key and the New Record as the value
            oldRecToNewRec.put(oldObj.id, newObj);


            if (doInsert) {
                insert oldRecToNewRec.values();

                //Store the old to new IDs
                for (ID i : oldRecToNewRec.keySet()) {
                    oldIDToNewID.put(i, oldRecToNewRec.get(i).id);
                }

                if (withChildren) {
                    //Get the related Objects
                    childRelationships = getRelatedObjects(objtype);

                    //Fire off the clone children which will call this method in a cyclic fashion
                    //until all children and their children are cloned
                    cloneChildren(oldRecToNewRec.keySet(), childRelationships);
                }
            }

            //Add the record to the final results by Object type
            results.put(objtype, oldRecToNewRec.values());


        }

        return results;
    }

    /******************************************************************************
    *
    *   Get children of object and clone them as well
    *
    *******************************************************************************/

    private static void cloneChildren(Set<ID> pIds, Map<Schema.SObjectType, Schema.sObjectField[]> pFields) {

        /*
            Currently no checks on limits
            This method will do 1 query and 1 dml for each group of child objects
            If those objects have children it will continue to add to the counts
         */

        //Each child relationship field has its own type so we will need to go through each type and attempt to clone the records
        for (Schema.sObjectType cObjType : pFields.keySet()) {
            Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objTypeDescribe = cObjType.getDescribe();

            if (objTypeDescribe.isCreateable() == false ||
                    objTypeDescribe.getName().endsWithIgnoreCase('share') ||
                    excludedObjects.contains(objTypeDescribe.getName())) continue;

            String[] pFieldNames = new String[]{};

            //Get a List of Fields related to Parent Object
            for (Schema.SObjectField pFld : pFields.get(cObjType))
                pFieldNames.add(pFld.getDescribe().getName());


            //build the where clause - Just in case there are multiple fields related to the same SObjectType
            String pFieldWhere = '';
            for (String pFld : pFieldNames) {
                if (pFieldWhere != '') pFieldWhere += ' OR ';
                pFieldWhere += pFld + ' IN :rIds';
            }

            //Query for values - using rIds in the Where clause as the method uses that variable name for pIds here
            Map<ID, sObject> childRecords = New Map<ID, SObject>(queryForRecords(cObjType, pIds, pFieldWhere));
//            system.debug(logginglevel.error, childRecords);

            if (!childRecords.isEmpty()) {
                Map<Schema.SObjectType, sObject[]> newChildren = cloneObjects(childRecords.values(), true, false);

                for (sObject newChild : newChildren.get(cObjType)) {
//                    system.debug(logginglevel.error, 'Starting replace of Parent IDs');
                    for (String pField : pFieldNames) {
//                        system.debug(logginglevel.error, 'pField: ' + pField);
                        Object oPid = newChild.get(pField);
//                        system.debug(logginglevel.error, 'Old pId: ' + oPid);
                        if (oPid != null && oldIDToNewID.get((ID) oPid) != null) {
//                            system.debug(logginglevel.error, 'New pId: ' + oldIDToNewID.get((ID) oPid));
                            newChild.put(pField, oldIDToNewID.get((ID) oPid));
                        }
                    }
                }

                insert newChildren.get(cObjType);
            }
        }
    }


    /******************************************************************************
    *
    *   Query for Records to Clone
    *       Getting the ObjectType from the ID Set
    *       Ensuring that there is only one ObjectType
    *
    *******************************************************************************/

    @TestVisible private static sObject[] queryForRecords(Set<ID> rIds, String customWhereClause) {
        if (rIds == null || rIds.isEmpty()) return new sObject[]{};

        Schema.SObjectType oType;

        //Just a double check to ensure that once we get here there is only 1 object type to query
        for (ID rId : rIds) {
            if (oType == null) {
                oType = rId.getSObjectType();
            } else {
                if (rId.getSobjectType() != oType)
                    throw New Object_Clone_Exception(TOMANYTYPES);
            }
        }

        return queryForRecords(oType, rIds, customWhereClause);
    }

    /******************************************************************************
    *
    *   Query for Records to Clone - Main Method
    *       Requires Single Known ObjectType
    *
    *******************************************************************************/

    private static sObject[] queryForRecords(Schema.sObjectType oType, Set<ID> rIds, String customWhereClause) {
//        system.debug(logginglevel.error, oType);
//        system.debug(logginglevel.error, oType);

        if (rIds == null || rIds.isEmpty()) return New SObject[]{};

        String[] fldsToClone = getCreateableFields(oType);
        system.debug(logginglevel.error, fldsToClone);

        String query = 'Select ID, ';

        query += string.join(fldsToClone, ',');


        query += ' From ' + oType; // + ' Where ID IN :rIds';

        if (customWhereClause != null) {
            query += ' Where ' + customWhereClause;
        } else {
            query += ' Where ID IN :rIds';
        }
        system.debug(logginglevel.error, query);
        return database.query(query);

    }





    /******************************************************************************
    *
    *   Gets Creatable Fields
    *
    *******************************************************************************/
    private static String[] getCreateableFields(Schema.sObjectType obj) {
        String[] results = New String[]{
        };


        for (Schema.sObjectField fld : obj.getDescribe().fields.getMap().values()) {

            Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = fld.getDescribe();

            //ignore Unique fields. They will have to be filled in manually
            if (!dfr.isUnique() && (dfr.isCreateable() || dfr.isUpdateable())) {
                results.add(dfr.getName());
            }
        }


        return results;

    }

    /******************************************************************************
    *
    *   Gets Relationship Fields
    *       - Returning the SobjectType and the Relationship Field on that object
    *
    *******************************************************************************/


    private static Map<Schema.SObjectType, Schema.sObjectField[]> getRelatedObjects(Schema.sObjectType obj) {

        Map<Schema.SObjectType, Schema.sObjectField[]> results = New Map<Schema.SObjectType, Schema.sObjectField[]>();

        for (ChildRelationship r: obj.getDescribe().getChildRelationships()) {
            Schema.SObjectField[] tmp = results.get(r.getChildSObject());
            if (tmp == null) tmp = New Schema.SObjectField[]{};
            tmp.add(r.getField());
            results.put(r.getChildSObject(), tmp);
        }

        return results;

    }

    private static void setexcludedObjects(Set<String> userExcludedObjects) {
        //List of all object that are excluded from cloning
        Set<String> tmp = New Set<String>();

        Set<String> alwaysExclude = New Set<String>{
                'CollaborationGroupRecord'
        };

        if (userExcludedObjects != null) {
            for (String obj : userExcludedObjects)
                tmp.add(obj);
        }

        tmp.addAll(alwaysExclude);

        excludedObjects = tmp;
    }


    /******************************************************************************
    *
    *   Gets Error Thrown
    *
    *******************************************************************************/

    public static String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorThrown;
    }

}
```

**Test Class 100% but needs adding methods for your use case**

```
@IsTest
private class Object_Clone_Tests {


    static testMethod void basicTestSingleNoChildren() {
        Account a = New Account(Name = 'Test Account',BillingCity = 'Test City');
        insert a;

        Contact c = New Contact(LastName = 'Last', FirstName = 'First', AccountId = a.id);
        insert c;

        Object_Clone.cloneObjectSingle(a.id,false);

        Account[] clonedAccount = [Select Name, BillingCity From Account Where ID != :a.id];

        system.assertEquals(1,clonedAccount.size(), 'More than one account was created');

        //Clear out the values that would never match
        a.id = null;
        clonedAccount[0].id = null;

        system.assertEquals(a,clonedAccount[0]);

        Contact[] newContact = [Select LastName,FirstName From Contact Where ID != :c.id];

        system.assertEquals(true,newContact.isEmpty(),'A contact record was created when nochildren was set to false');

    }

    static testMethod void basicTestSingleWhithChildren() {
        Account a = New Account(Name = 'Test Account',BillingCity = 'Test City');
        insert a;

        Contact c = New Contact(LastName = 'Last', FirstName = 'First', AccountId = a.id);
        insert c;

        Object_Clone.cloneObjectSingle(a.id,true);

        //Assert Records were created and linked
        Account[] clonedAccount = [Select Name, BillingCity From Account Where ID != :a.id];

        system.assertEquals(1,clonedAccount.size(), 'More than one account was created');

        Contact[] newContact = [Select LastName,FirstName, AccountID From Contact Where ID != :c.id];

        system.assertEquals(1,newContact.size(),'A contact record was created when nochildren was set to false');

        system.assertEquals(clonedAccount[0].id,newContact[0].AccountId,'The cloned Contact AccountID was not set to the cloned Account ID');

        //Assert they are equals sans the Ids
        a.id = null;
        clonedAccount[0].id = null;
        system.assertEquals(a,clonedAccount[0]);


        //Clear out the values that would never match
        c.id = null;
        c.AccountId = null;
        newContact[0].id = null;
        newContact[0].AccountId = null;
    }

    static testMethod void basicTestWithChildrenExcludeContact() {
        Account a = New Account(Name = 'Test Account',BillingCity = 'Test City');
        insert a;

        Contact c = New Contact(LastName = 'Last', FirstName = 'First', AccountId = a.id);
        insert c;

        Object_Clone.cloneObjectWithExclude(New Set<ID>{a.id},true,New Set<String>{'Contact'});

        Account[] clonedAccount = [Select Name, BillingCity From Account Where ID != :a.id];

        system.assertEquals(1,clonedAccount.size(), 'More than one account was created');

        //Clear out the values that would never match
        a.id = null;
        clonedAccount[0].id = null;

        system.assertEquals(a,clonedAccount[0]);

        Contact[] newContact = [Select LastName,FirstName From Contact Where ID != :c.id];

        system.assertEquals(true,newContact.isEmpty(),'A contact record was created when Contact was excluded');

    }


    static testMethod void noRecordsError(){
        Object_Clone.cloneObjectSingle(null,false);
        system.assertEquals(Object_Clone.NORECORDS,Object_Clone.getErrorMessage());

        Object_Clone.cloneObjectSet(New Set<ID>(), false);
        system.assertEquals(Object_Clone.NORECORDS,Object_Clone.getErrorMessage());

    }

    static testMethod void toManyTypesError(){

        Account a = New Account(Name = 'Test Account',BillingCity = 'Test City');
        insert a;

        Contact c = New Contact(LastName = 'Last', FirstName = 'First', AccountId = a.id);
        insert c;

        try {
            Object_Clone.queryForRecords(New Set<ID>{a.id, c.id}, null);
            system.assertEquals(false,true,'An error (TOO MANY TYPES) was supposed to be thrown and caught, thus we should have never made it here');
        }catch(Object_Clone.Object_Clone_Exception e) {
            system.assertEquals(Object_Clone.TOMANYTYPES, e.getMessage());
        }


    }

    static testMethod void NoExclusionsSet(){

        system.assertNotEquals(null,Object_Clone.excludedObjects, 'The Exclusion returned null when it should have been an empty list');
        system.assertEquals(true,Object_Clone.excludedObjects.isEmpty(),'The Exclusions were not empty despite the setter not being executed');

    }

    //TODO - Bulk Tests
    static testmethod void bulkClone(){

    }

}
```

**Clone Quote Button**

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/35.0/connection.js")} //adds the proper code for inclusion of AJAX toolkit 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/35.0/apex.js")}

var status = sforce.apex.execute("Object_Clone","cloneObjectSingle",{oId: '{!Quote.Id}', withChildren: true});

if(status != ''){
      parent.location.href = status;
}else{
  alert('There was an error cloning the quote');
}
```

Comment: excellent answer; in practice, one generally also needs some list of field exclusions to avoid cloning createable fields that are nonsensical (based on the org's business rules). For example, cloning an Opportunity that is closed won to a new closed won Oppo could cause issues

Comment: @Eric thank you for the code, it looks great. I need to edit the values, before inserting/ cloning the record, like crop1645 said, i don't want to copy everything. Anyway, still greate piece of code and information. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing url hacking passing the parameters [clone=1,id=Quote.Id... ]

if you want to include other fields you need to specify them in the parameter list and ensure those fields are displayed on the page layout..

here is a guide to url hacking:

http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-to-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-page-layout.html