# clone commandbutton using VisualForce and $Action

Tags: visualforce

I need to clone a record displayed via VisualForce. Created this button which works eventually but does not open the cloned page in the proper record type:

Using either formats seems to open the object as an  format and not using the VisualForce page I launched the clone button from. If I save this detail page it is then presented in the proper VisualForce page. Short of writing a method in the controller is there a practical way to do this?

```
<apex:commandButton value="Clone" action="{!URLFOR($Action.Account_Summary__c.Clone,Account_Summary__c.id)}"/>

<apex:commandButton value="Clone2" action="{!URLFOR($Action.Account_Summary__c.Clone,Id,[retURL=Id],true)}"/>
```

This syntax opens the record in a VisualForce page but none of the field values set on the original carry over to the cloned VisualForce page.

```
<apex:commandButton value="Clone3x" action="{!URLFOR('/apex/PROD_UW_AccountSummary', Id, [retUrl=Id,clone='true',name=Account_Summary__c.Name, cid=Id], true)}&RecordType=0120S0000004XY4QAM" />
```

Comment: Clone is going to take you to an edit page with the parameters clone=1 and id=recordId... If you want to directly clone the record without the intermediate page, you'll need to write Apex Code.

Comment: OK. Is there something on the intermediate page that I can read to un-render a large part of the page so it looks cleaner? I'll ask another question on sample apex code to create a clone.

Comment: Looking at this intermediate page further its opened as a Force.com page and not a VisualForce page. So it does not seem possible to using rendering to hide anything. It is using the same record type as the original record. Do you think its possible to have the intermediate page open in a new record type containing just the fields I need, use a custom 'Save' button that sets the recordtype back to the original so it opens properly in VisualForce ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may need to just add the url for the page/ add parameters to the current page like below:

```
<apex:page  standardController="Jurisdiction__c">
   <apex:form>
   <apex:pageBlock title="{!Jurisdiction__c.Name}" rendered="{!OR($CurrentPage.parameters.clone = 'false', $CurrentPage.parameters.clone = null)}">
       <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
          <apex:commandButton value="Clone" action="{!URLFOR('/apex/Test', Id, [retUrl=Id,clone='true',name=Jurisdiction__c.Name, cid=Id], true)}" />
       </apex:pageBlockButtons>
       <apex:outputField value="{!Jurisdiction__c.Name}" />
       <apex:outputField value="{!Jurisdiction__c.Id}" />
   </apex:pageBlock>

   <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.clone='true'}">
       <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
           <apex:inputField value="{!Jurisdiction__c.Name}" />
           <apex:inputField value="{!Jurisdiction__c.OwnerId}" />
       </apex:pageBlockSection>
   </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>
```

I just used a generic custom object here to illustrate this - you can substitute for your own object for testing but would see the below in the screens below: 
View Page: 
[image: View Page]

Clone View: 
[image: Clone view]

you'll notice that the URL holds the parameters you need - you can populate the fields if you want in Javascript pulling the values from the parameters

URL after clone button clicked:

apex/Test?nooverride=1&retUrl=a07o000000LxNdn&clone=true&name=OVA&cid=a07o000000LxNdn

Comment: Thanks Ronnie. I was trying to figure something similar out. I have 3 record types for the object but I think doing this will simply use the current recordtypename hosting the the clone button. I'll try this and provide an update.

Comment: you could control the record type or even give options for that to be selected by using a Custom Metadata Type and a controller here too which would offer a little more automation to that selection or flexibility in the selection with a custom built picklist

Comment: Yes. I only want to keep one record type as the current version. The others are older non VF pages that will open for historical viewing. Any clone should use the same one from the parent at this point.

Comment: just add the record typeid to the params

<apex:commandButton value="Clone" action="{!URLFOR('/apex/Test', Id, [retUrl=Id,clone='true',name=Jurisdiction__c.Name, cid=Id;recordTypeId=Jurisdiction__c.RecordTypeId], true)}" />


just for example

Comment: this works to open a VisualForce page with the recordtypeID needed. However, there are allot of fields on the original that do not come over with the clone in this way. They do if I use the $action syntax. Is there anyway to specify a 'copyAll' when using this syntax?  <apex:commandButton value="Clone3x" action="{!URLFOR('/apex/PROD_UW_AccountSummary', Id, [retUrl=Id,clone='true',name=Account_Summary__c.Name, cid=Id], true)}&RecordType=0120S0000004XY4QAM" />

Comment: Maybe something here might work for you - if using only VF Page: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/100026/custom-clone-button-on-quote-copies-few-standard-fields-but-not-all-why

or something here - if you want to do this using Apex and VF: 

http://christopheralunlewis.blogspot.com/2012/04/clone-plus-clone-salesforce-objects.html

i do like the second option more as you can also work with deep cloning ( cloning related objects )

Comment: as far as pulling in all fields .. you could as well work with jQuery and store the sObject in a variable and work with that as well to populate and build your page out as you want

Comment: Thanks Ronnie. I like the second option as well. The first is an interesting hack but may be more complex to maintain in the future. I just need to create a clone with its own ID and no reference to the original object.

Comment: by the way this object has hundreds of fields that would all need to be copied into the clone. But only those that are 'not' null.

Comment: i think you would need to pass the SObject to the front end or handle cloning onthe back end in a controller then to copy directly - using standard controller alone with no Apex code on the back end - you will only get the ID when referencing in Javascript - you could store the sObject in a variable if it is on the backend in a variable - but that defeats doing this all with just code - you will need to use a controller which again, i'd prefer that route over just page level and when you rerender the page

Comment: - the standard controller will only load the fields that are referenced on the page - so if there were values that you don't have - you will need to query for them i'd use schema and build a query string so you don't need to long term manage changes to/deletion of fields and API names

Comment: I agree. The blog you mentioned has a previous article on just cloning the object / properties and not all child objects (which I don't need - http://christopheralunlewis.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/how-to-dynamically-clone-salesforce.html )  Also, using the $actions that shows the Sobject to the user only requires that the fields needed are on the layout page. So I'll start with that then move to the controller approach. Of course it would be great if SalesForce allowed for a VisualForce page returnURL when cloning.